# Agile Web Development with Rails Book Create Product Test Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am getting this error message when I run my tests, the relevant features work when tested in the browser.

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
StandardError: No fixture named 'three' found for fixture set 
'products'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in 
<class:ProductsControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:24

Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
StandardError: No fixture named 'three' found for fixture set 
'products'
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in 
<class:ProductsControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:14
```

Here are my tests which i have checked carefully.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @product = products(:three)
    @update = {
        tite:         'lorxem Ipsum',
        description:  'Wibbles are fun!',
        image_url:    'lorem.jpg',
        price:        19.95
    }
  end

  test "should get index" do  
    get products_url
    assert_response :success
  end

 test "should get new" do
    get new_product_url
    assert_response :success
 end

  test "should create product" do
   assert_difference('Product.count') do
   post products_url, params: { product: @update }
  end

  assert_redirected_to product_url(Product.last)
end

  test "should show product" do
    get product_url(@product)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_product_url(@product)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update product" do
    patch product_url(@product), params: { product: @update }
    assert_redirected_to product_url(@product)
  end

  test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
      delete product_url(@product)
   end

    assert_redirected_to products_url
  end
```

end

And here are my fixtures

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: test.jpg
  price: 9.99

two:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: test.jpg
  price: 9.99
```

Here is my add product controller code which works in the broweser:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was 
successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: 
@product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: 
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is my update product controller code which again works in the browser:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was 
successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: 
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help or guidance appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the test logs:

```
ProductsControllerTest: test_should_create_product
--------------------------------------------------
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 980190962], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-08 08:35:35 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"product"=>{"tite"=>"lorxem Ipsum", "description"=>"Wibbles are fun!", "image_url"=>"lorem.jpg", "price"=>"19.95"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :tite
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Product Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."title" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Rendering products/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/_form.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 7.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

One of the test now passes - the update one - the products in fixtures had the same title and title validates to uniqueness hence failure.

Any help with the create product test would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a product fixture that is not present in your products fixture file.  `@product = products(:three)` expects to find a fixture named :three in the products.yml file, but you only have :one and :two.  Either create a new product three fixture or change change `products(:three)` to `products(:one)` or `products(:two)`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I had changed that in my efforts to track the problem.  Changing it back to products(:one) doesn't change the error messages unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, looking at the logs I get this, why is it failing, too long so edited above.

Answer (score 0):

managed to work this out, the issue was: `tite:         'lorxem Ipsum',` should have been `title:         'lorxem Ipsum',`

A missing "l"!